# How to using Eloquent groupBy and orderBy in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eloquent, laravel-5.5

```
\App\Service::groupBy('type')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

I am using laravel 5.5..
Can help me for resolve this problem..?

Error report

"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db_name.tbl_name.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tbl_name` group by `type` order by `id` desc) "

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: '*Can help me for resolve this problem..?*' - We can't help resolve anything unless you help us a provide an error or more details to go off. Help us help you. Please, take the [tour].

Comment: You can't use `orderBy` before `groupBy` mover your `orderBy` clause after `groupBy`

Comment: I change my code to
\App\Service::groupBy('type')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
Error report say:
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bramajaya.tbl_service.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tbl_service` group by `type` order by `id` desc) "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tablename.fieldname' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `tablename` group by `fieldname`)
```

Then edit your database config file `config/database.php`

In mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode

Comment: Success.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When grouping in MySQL you can only work with either fields you are grouping by or fields used in aggregate functions of your select. Therefore `orderBy('id', 'DESC')` will do nothing in your case.